# Creating Rails object with Curl - validation is not seeing attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

my Rails app has Posts, and each Post belongs to a Book. I am working on an API for an iOS app.

When I run this curl command, it gets a 500 error saying "book_id can't be blank." Since I included book_id in the command, I am not sure why? Thanks for your help!

Post.rb

```
validates :book_id, presence: true
```

curl command

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -H 'X-API-EMAIL: me@mail.com'   -H 'X-API-TOKEN: cQTqKfo3Zxqvr8k1Jn6vxyEEnbGnnG9g'   -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/posts   -d '{"post" : { "book_id" : "713", "comment" : "great book"}}'
```

Comment: 'twould be helpful to include the controller code that you hit with that POST.

Comment: of course when I went to copy that over I realized I was missing book_id under post_params :-( thanks!